# Bypass power steering pump?

Tags: power-steering

Has anyone successfully deleted lines or looped high pressure side back into power steering pump to starve leaking rack and pinion while lubing pump spindle? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

The power steering hoses were never meant to loop in on themselves so you will most likely end up destroying them while making the switch over. Theoretically what you are asking is possible. That being said it's not recommended. The rack is geared to steer with power assist, 3 turns lock to lock normally. The car would be very difficult to steer with no assist. If you think it will be just like any other car with no factory power assist you are wrong. Normal non power assist is 5 turns lock to lock, a much different gearing.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to do this? It would be relatively easy to accomplish but the Vehicle would not be fun to drive due to having to push the power steering rack back and forth with every turn of the Steering wheel. I would assume the Rack would quickly fail as well making things really dicey for safety!!!!

Comment: Because non-PAS steering provides a far better feel BUT non-PAS steering racks are generally slower (more turns, lock-to-lock).  Using a quick rack without any power assistance is very common in various forms of motorsport.